# Framework.Log error referencia c#

Tags: c#

Hola amigos tengo un error de referencia en mi proyecto en Visual Studio que es Framework.Log alguien sabe ha que se de debe? ya que esa dependencia lo utilizo en una clase para manejar los errores

Comment: En que parte de tu codigo? cual es el error completo que te da? vas a tenernos que dar mas contexto para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: sale error en : using Framework.Log;

Comment: Que error? te tira un error el using? tenes esa libreria referenciada?

Comment: Si si tengo, pero me sale el triangulo de advertensia en la referencia , parece que no esta instalada pero lo busco no encuentro